# ServiceNow integration with Microsoft Sentinel - customDetails error

Tags: integration, servicenow, azure-sentinel

I'm encountering issues with fetching alert `customDetails` from Microsoft Sentinel where i get following error message:

> "Error retrieving Custom Details from Log Analytics for alert: ReferenceError: 'LogAnalyticsWorkspace' is not defined."

Could anyone provide insight into why this error might be occurring and how to resolve it?

I've already configured `laapiendpoint` and `laworkspaceid` in the workspace settings. However, when attempting to fetch the details, I'm faced with an error message.